# Single node returned after XML deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

**I have below xml structure**

```
<root>
 <title>List</title>
 <units>Total Units: 79.0</units>
 <sesgrps>
   <sesgrp>
     <classes>
       <class>
         <subj_area_name>C# language</subj_area_name>
         <class_name>C# Class</class_name>
       </class>
       <class>
         <subj_area_name>VB language</subj_area_name>
         <class_name>VB Class</class_name>
       </class>
       <class>
         <subj_area_name>F# language</subj_area_name>
         <class_name>F# Class</class_name>
       </class>
     </classes>
   </sesgrp>
</sesgrps>
```

**For that I have created classes as below:**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("units")]
    public string Units { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("sesgrps")]
    [XmlArrayItem("sesgrp")]
    public List<SessionGroup> SessionGroups { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SessionGroup
{
    [XmlArray("classes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("class")]
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Class
{
   .....................
   .....................
}
```

When I **deserialize**, I am only **getting single Class item instead of 3 class Items** in Classes collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried following code:

```
var file = new FileStream("Input.txt", FileMode.Open);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
var item = (Data)serializer.Deserialize(file);
```

with your input XML data and following `Class` class declaration:

```
[Serializable]
public class Class
{
    [XmlElement("subj_area_name")]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("class_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And everything is fine. Result item has 1 `SessionGroup` instance withing `SessionGroups` property, which contains 3 `Class` objects within `Classes` property:

[image]

So I have to say - `XmlSerializer` or class declarations are not a problem here.

Comment: Thanks...I had some issue with the nodes in "Class" class, due to which only the first node was coming. There was mismatch in xml structure and object structure. Thanks again.